# i have a problem filter datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

i have this query:

```
select b.observation, b.created_date (datetime field)
FROM logistics_wms.reception_documents a
join logistics_wms.reception b on a.reception_id = b.id
join logistics_wms.document c on a.documents_id = c.id
join logistics_wms.document_type d on d.id = c.document_type_id
join logistics_wms.document_line e on c.id = e.document_id
join logistics_wms.product g on e.product_id = g.id
where b.status = 'SUBMITTED'
and b.created_date >= '2020-04-01 00:00:00'
```

i used '2020-04-01' too

And the result is:

[image: >= '2020-04-01']

but if i used:

```
select b.observation, b.created_date (datetime field)
FROM logistics_wms.reception_documents a
join logistics_wms.reception b on a.reception_id = b.id
join logistics_wms.document c on a.documents_id = c.id
join logistics_wms.document_type d on d.id = c.document_type_id
join logistics_wms.document_line e on c.id = e.document_id
join logistics_wms.product g on e.product_id = g.id
where b.status = 'SUBMITTED'
and b.created_date >= '2020-04-15 00:00:00'
```

i used '2020-04-15' too

the result is:

[image: >= '2020-04-15]

why when i select 2020-04-01 the query doesn´t get the last two records of the second query??!!

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: This is weird. What happens if you add `ORDER BY b.created_date DESC` to the end of your queries?

Comment: Which tool do you use to run this query? Also post the create statement of the table `reception`.

Comment: its a report tool, BIRT

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that time has no importance in your case (00:00:00), it is much simpler to use MySQL DATE function in your filter. Can you try using :
`where b.status = 'SUBMITTED' and DATE(b.created_date) >= '2020-04-01'`
and
`where b.status = 'SUBMITTED' and DATE(b.created_date) >= '2020-04-15'`

Comment: thank you for the reply. But unfortanly the result was the some, when i put >= '2020-04-01' i still cant see the two records 16/04  11  alter 16/04/2020, 09:53
16/04 15 L´OREAL 16/04/2020, 10:31

Comment: Unfortunately, when you apply a function like `DATE()` to a column in  a `WHERE` clause you prevent the DBMS from using an index on that column. @Hugo Araujo's code is correct in this respect.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that... Have you the same result in short ISO format ? where b.created_date >= '20200415' ?